# Unable to pass JSON Data to MVC Controller using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my QUIZ application, I want to send an array of objects (in which one question with four answers & one correct answer  as a property of an object) to MVC Controller but it sends null value. The key point to solve this issue was to stringify the JSON object, define a model and get the parameter as the defined model. Is there any Alternative Solution for this?

My View UI Look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pxq36e2L/)

//VIEW Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
            createquestions();
        });
        function createquestions()
        {
            var things = [];
            var nofques = $("#ddlnofquestions").val();//Coming from Dropdown Value
            for (var i = 1; i <= nofques; i++) {
                var obj = {
                    id: i,
                    question:  CKEDITOR.instances[i.toString()].getData(),
                    answer1:$("#" + i + 1).val(),
                    answer2: $("#" + i + 2).val(),
                    answer3: $("#" + i + 3).val(),
                    answer4: $("#" + i + 4).val(),
                    correctanswer: $("#" + i + 5).val(),                  
                };                
                things.push(obj);               
            }
            var thingss = JSON.stringify({ "things": things });
            $.ajax({    
                type: 'POST',
                url:'Question/CreateQuestion',
                async:true,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                data: { things: JSON.stringify(things) },
                traditonal: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Sucessfully Created");
                },
          });
        }
    });
</script>
```

C#: Model Class

```
public class CreateQuestion
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer1 { get; set; }
    public string answer2 { get; set; }
    public string answer3 { get; set; }
    public string answer4 { get; set; }
    public string correctanswer { get; set; }
}
```

C#: Controller

```
public ActionResult CreateQuestion(List<CreateQuestion> things)
{
    //where we try to get an array of objects
    //Working Code......
    return View();    
}
```

Comment: I think this is quite a nice solution. Maybe your question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this on your AJAX call:

```
data: { things: JSON.stringify(things) },
```

For this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(things),
```

What I think is happening is that the action is expecting a list of objects, but on the AJAX call, you are sending an object that contains an array of objects.

Comment: I also do that but both the solution are also not useful.

Thank you so much for giving the solution

Answer (score 0):

You may try do something like:

[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult CreateQuestion( POCOthings)

Where POCOthings is an POCO objet suitable to be transformed by mvc model binder.
For your case you list of CreateQuestions should be a field of said object.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried your's solution but it gives the same response i.e null value

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check.

1. is it 404 error? httppost attribute missing for action.
2. is JSON.stringify(things) a valid object?
3. can you try removing dataType? you are returning view but the data type it is expecting is json.

> dataType: 'json',

Comment: I have already these three things but still its showing a null value.

Thanku so much for giving the nice solution

Comment: I would try running fiddler simultaneously, check its url, form body etc.